# Printing the instantiation of a class exposes private variables

Tags: php, security, oop

In PHP, I have created a class that contains privately declared variables.

```
class testClass {
   private $_db_name = 'test_db';
   private $_db_user = 'test_user';
   private $_db_pass = 'test_pass';
}
```

Accidentally, after instantiating the class, I ran a `print_r` on the variable I set and it printed these private variables to the screen.

```
$test = new testClass();
print_r($test);
```

Returns:

```
testClass Object
(
    [_db_name:testClass:private] => test_db
    [_db_user:testClass:private] => test_user
    [_db_pass:testClass:private] => test_pass
)
```

This is somewhat of a concern for me. If I packaged a class with sensitive information in it on my server for others to include and utilize without needing access to passwords, etc, they could simply dump these. Am I missing something critical here to prevent this behavior from happening? Is there a better way to handle sensitive information in an object?

Comment: "If I packaged a class with sensitive information in it on my server for others to include" - wait... do not do this. Really. This is what web services are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting members to private is not meant for security in the way you look at it (i.e. to hide sensitive data). It simply is security against other people (developers) using the members in extended classes or throughout the application.

It is **not** meant to protect data from being shared with people who shouldn't be able to see it. If you don't want others to be able to see it don't include it in code others are utilizing.

Long story short. The visibility is just to prevent the junior developers to screw things up or make a mess of your code. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I was under the wrong impression about the "security" of private scoped variables.

Answer (score 0):

If they can access the PHP code, they can access everything in it. You could prevent it from being in the `print_r` function by not declaring them as variables but handling it in `final public function __get($prop)`

```
final public function __get($prop) {
  switch ($prop) {
    case "_db_name":
     return 'test_db';

  }

  return $this->$prop; //this also works on all private vars, so you might want some extra checking.
}
```

But then again, if I can add your package like `require('your/package/file.php')` then what is preventing me from doing `echo implode('', file('your/package/file.php'));` to see it?